# How to read channel messages with simple-slack-api?

Tags: java, slack, slack-api

I'm using [simple-slack-api](https://github.com/Ullink/simple-slack-api) with Java, but I can not find a way to read messages from a specific channel. My code is the following:

```
public void getChannelMessages(String channelName) throws IOException{

    SlackChannel channel = slackSession_.findChannelByName(channelName);


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read message from a channel you need to fetch the history of that channel.

From the examples:

```
    /**
     * This method how to get the message history from a given channel (by default, 1000 max messages are fetched)
     */
    public void fetchSomeMessagesFromChannelHistory(SlackSession session, SlackChannel slackChannel)
    {
        //build a channelHistory module from the slack session
        ChannelHistoryModule channelHistoryModule = ChannelHistoryModuleFactory.createChannelHistoryModule(session);

        List<SlackMessagePosted> messages = channelHistoryModule.fetchHistoryOfChannel(slackChannel.getId());
}
```

See the [full example](https://github.com/Ullink/simple-slack-api/blob/master/samples/actions/src/main/java/actions/FetchingMessageHistory.java) from the git for more details.